# Get rails route to reflect database lisiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, router, rails-routing

I currently have a page that searched through a listings database. On clicking a selection, the view links to that listing's show page:

```
<div class="listings_wrapper">
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <%= link_to listing_url(listing), class: "listing_link" do %>
  <div class="listing">
    <div class="picture">
      <% if listing.thumbnail != nil %>
        <%= image_tag(listing.thumbnail, class: "list_image") %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

The show page that is currently routed as:

```
  get 'listings/:listing_id', to: 'listings#show', as: 'listing'
```

which will get me the address

```
  localhost3000/listing/612983618 (arbitrary id)
```

What I'm trying to do is get the route to display information from the database in the route instead, for SEO purposes:

```
  localhost3000/listing/[address]/[booking_id]
```

When I try to adjust to

```
  get 'listings/:listing_id', to: 'listings#show', as: 'listing/:address/:booking_id'
```

I get blocked on loading. I've been looking around stackoverflow at similar answers, but haven't got my head around this problem as of yet. Since the link is pulling the object itself, and the route is pulling the id from that, it would make sense to refer to the :address key instead, but something is clearly missing.  Help?

Comment: What you have as alias, use it as the uri, like `get 'listing/:address/:booking_id', to: 'listings#show'` you should make sure on adding the address and booking_id when invoking that route.

Comment: right, I get : no route matches (database entry) ....missing required keys: [:booking_id] when I try that...

Comment: Are you rendering a link to that route? Add that to the question.

Comment: It might be the view...I'm taking over this from another developer, so I sdon't know the ins and outs of this particular app:        
`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :address=>#<Listing id: 1, booking_id: "N4043290", ........address: "sample_address", ......">, :controller=>"listings"} missing required keys: [:booking_id]):
    120: <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    121:   <%= link_to listing_url(listing), class: "listing_link" do %>
    122:   <div class="listing">
    124:       <% if listing.thumbnail != nil %>`

Comment: Where do you get the address and booking_id? from the listing object? if so, try being more explicit `listing_url(booking_id: listing.booking_id, address: listing.address)`.

Comment: Getting there? the controller's barking at me now, so progress?       `@listing = Listing.find(params(:address, :mls))` `(wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the URI for `listings#show` to receive the address and booking_id of the object, then you could move the alias in your route definition to the uri argument, like:

```
get 'listing/:address/:booking_id', to: 'listings#show'
```

Now it'll be waiting both attributes. While in your controller if you want to find that specific object from both sent attributes, then you can use [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

```
@listing = Listing.find_by(adress: params[:address], booking_id: params[:booking_id]) 
@listings = Listing.last(3)
```

Note this will work, but in case you have more than one record with same address and booking_id, find_by will just return the first one.

Comment: Got this working! There was a redundancy in the views that was blocking it from working before (long story), but it looks great now.